# Question on applying Ito's formula in this proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am reviewing [this paper](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/~pardoux/PaPeng1.pdf) and I'm on page 3 of the document, and I'm having trouble with the proof of uniqueness.

First off, the version of Ito's lemma I've learned is: if $X_{t}$ is an Ito process (i.e., $X_{t} = X_{0} + \int \limits_{0}^{t} b(s, \omega) \,ds + \int \limits_{0}^{t} a(s,\omega) \, dB_{s}$) and if $f$ is twice differentiable, then $$f(X_{t}) = f(X_{0}) + \int \limits_{0}^{t} f'(X_{s}) b(s, \omega) \,ds + a(s,\omega) \,dB_{s} + \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{t} f''(X_{s}) a^{2}(s, \omega) \,ds.  $$

**My first question is**: How would Ito's formula be different considering the paper is dealing with Backward Stochastic Differential Equations where the limits of integration are from $t$ to $1$?

Now, the authors suppose that there are two solutions $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2})$. They apply Ito's formula to $(x_{1} - x_{2})^{2}$.  I'm assuming here that the $f$ from the Ito's formula I have above is $f(x) = x^{2}$, which is $C^{2}$.

**My next questions are**: I don't really understand how they applied Ito's formula to get the resulting equation.  It seems like the integrand in each integral is a vector with one of the components the function $x_{1} - x_{2}$.  Where did this come from?

Comment: Update a few weeks later: for the second question, the $(\cdot, \cdot)$ notation represents the dot product!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question: The $0$ and $t$ in the typical statement of Ito's Lemma aren't required.  In general you can say:
$$f(X_{v}) = f(X_{u}) + \int \limits_{u}^{v} f'(X_{s}) b(s, \omega) \,ds + a(s,\omega) \,dB_{s} + \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{u}^{v} f''(X_{s}) a^{2}(s, \omega) \,ds.  $$
Then set $u = 0, v = t$ for the typical statement, and $u = t, v = 1$ for the version used in the paper.

Regarding the second question: If you reexamine the definition of the processes in the proposition you will see their range is $\mathbb{R}^d$, so they are vector valued.  You need to use the [Multidimensional Ito's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D%27s_lemma) which you can find on that page.